# Parallize training of regression models for each group in a large dataset on spark (in databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

I am working with a large dataset which can be grouped by a Group_Key. I want to have as many regression models as number of groups. So I do the following,

1. I have a python function that takes in the training dataset for each group, tunes the hyperparameters and appends the best model to a pkl file.
2. I use applyInPandas method to call the training function on each group.

Training function:

```
def train_reg_model(df_train: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """ applyOnPandas called on this, so df_train should be grouped by key
    """
    fit_time = 0
    print('fitting')
    models_df, fit_time = fit_lgbm_all_bn(df_train)

    prj_fldr = "<path_to_folder>/model_pickles/"
    pickle_file_path = prj_fldr + 'models_df.pkl'
    # Call the append_to_pickle function
    append_to_pickle(models_df, pickle_file_path)
    
    #
    date_begin, date_end, date_mid = get_date_range(df_train)
    print(f"fit time: {fit_time}")
    print('done')
    select_cols = ['group_key', 'confidence']
    out_df = models_df[select_cols]
    out_df['date_begin'] = date_begin
    out_df['date_mid'] = date_mid
    out_df['date_end'] = date_end
    output_cols = ['date_begin', 'date_mid', 'date_end'] + select_cols
    return out_df[output_cols]
```

Then I call it using:

```
spark_df_out = spark_df.groupby(Group_Key).applyInPandas(train_reg_model,
                                          schema=out_schema)
pdf_out = spark_df_out.toPandas()
```

I did some benchmarking and found out that on average each fit takes 10-20s, maximum was 140s for a group with more data.

When I do `applyInPandas` for 100 groups it takes about 3 minutes. But when I increase it to 200 groups, it is still running for more than 3 hours. Eventually, I will have to process about 5000-10000 groups.

**Is there any way to optimize the run time? Am I missing something?**

I'm new to spark and did some digging and see a lot of warning like this one below:

```
23/07/06 15:25:57 WARN HangingTaskDetector: Task 1340 is probably not making progress because its metrics
(Map(internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBlocksFetched -> 1, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesReadToDisk -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.write.bytesWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.output.recordsWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.write.recordsWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.memoryBytesSpilled -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBytesRead -> 0, internal.metrics.diskBytesSpilled -> 0, 
internal.metrics.shuffle.read.localBytesRead -> 1003266, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.recordsRead -> 29975, internal.metrics.output.bytesWritten -> 0, internal.metrics.input.bytesRead -> 0, internal.metrics.input.recordsRead -> 0, internal.metrics.shuffle.read.remoteBlocksFetched -> 0)) has not changed since Thu Jul 06 13:32:27 UTC 2023
```

Thanks for your help :)